# Runtime Error when upgraded from java 11 to 17

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, quarkus-hibernate-orm

I'm getting this runtime error after upgrading java version from `11 to 17`, hibernate version used is `6.3.0.CR1`.
The same code works fine with Java 11

Error at runtime:

```
Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.query.BindableType.resolveExpressible(org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor)" because "declaredParameterType" is null
```

Comment: Any good reason to run on CR build when Final exists? I would test it on 6.3.0.Final or better 6.3.1.Final

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same error after upgrading from an older Hibernate version to Hibernate 6.2.13.FINAL, alongside a transition from javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence. While I can’t pinpoint the exact version that introduced the regression, the issue arose when preparing a named query:

```java
var query = entityManager
        .createNamedQuery("...")
        ...
        .setParameter(
            "eingangsdatum_von",
            eingangsdatumVon != null ? Date.from(eingangsdatumVon) : null,
            TemporalType.TIMESTAMP
        )
        .setParameter(
            "eingangsdatum_bis",
            eingangsdatumBis != null ? Date.from(eingangsdatumBis) : null,
            TemporalType.TIMESTAMP
        );
```

In the past, invoking setParameter on javax.persistence.Query with a null value for the date was permissible. However, post-upgrade, this is no longer the case, resulting in the exception you’ve encountered.

As a workaround, we now invoke setParameter on jakarta.persistence.Query with the date parameter only when it’s non-null. For null values, we use the overloaded setParameter method that accepts an Object.

To streamline the modification of all relevant calls, we crafted the following utility class:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.Query;
import jakarta.persistence.TemporalType;

import java.util.Date;

public final class HibernateQueryUtils {
    private HibernateQueryUtils() {

    }

    public static Query setParameter(Query query, String var1, Date var2, TemporalType var3) {
        if (var2 != null) {
            return query.setParameter(var1, var2, var3);
        }

        return query.setParameter(var1, null);
    }
}
```

And we utilize this method as follows:

```java
HibernateQueryUtils
    .setParameter(
        query,
        "eingangsdatum_von",
        eingangsdatumVon != null ? Date.from(eingangsdatumVon) : null,
        TemporalType.TIMESTAMP
    );

HibernateQueryUtils
    .setParameter(
        query,
        "eingangsdatum_bis",
        eingangsdatumBis != null ? Date.from(eingangsdatumBis) : null,
        TemporalType.TIMESTAMP
    );
```

This approach effectively bypasses the issue, allowing us to handle null values appropriately while preparing our queries.